# Angular 7 SSR window is not defined

Tags: angular7, server-side-rendering

I have a problem with Angular 7 SSR server side rendering window and document not found on server site. When run `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` then terminal showing reference error look like  `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

```
ngOnInit() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write in server.ts

```
/ ssr DOM
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
// index from browser build!
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
// for mock global window by domino
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
// from server build
const files = fs.readdirSync(`${process.cwd()}/dist-server`);
// mock
global['window'] = win;
```

more at https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts